# Sports Scheduler: Algorithm for generating a home and away schedule with a set number of games

Tags: algorithm, schedule

Hi all I've seen a few similar questions asked on here, but am wondering if there is a solution for a set number of games.

Here are my constraints:

1. Each team must play 10 games (or n games for a variable algorithm)
2. Each team can only play another team once
3. Each team must play 5 home and 5 away games (n/2 games)
4. Each team is in a division (A,B) and must play 5 games against each division (5 A games, 5 B games) (n/2 games per division)

I'm not sure what this sort of problem would be called or how to go about searching for information.

Most information I can find is for Round Robin schedules, not for a set number of games per season.

EDIT:
Found a forum thread that has helped: http://www.devenezia.com/round-robin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1260298921

Comment: I think it's called TTP - http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/TOURN/ttp_ipcp.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I also found a forum which has helped immensely (added in edit).